# How to combine multiple csv files on specific columns in a fast way?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataset

I have about 200 CSV files and I need to combine them on specific columns. Each CSV file contains 1000 filled rows on specific columns. My file names are like below:

> csv_files = [en_tr_translated0.csv, en_tr_translated1000.csv, en_tr_translated2000.csv, ......... , en_tr_translated200000.csv]

My csv file columns are like below:

[image]

The two first columns are prefilled up to same 200.000 rows/sentences in the all csv files. My each `en_tr_translated{ }.csv` files contains 1000 translated sentences related with their file name. For example:
`en_tr_translated1000.csv` file contains translated sentences from 0 to 1000th row, `en_tr_translated2000.csv` file contains translated sentences from 1000th to 2000th row etc. Rest is nan/empty. Below is an example image from `en_tr_translated3000.csv` file.

[image]

I want to copy/merge/join the rows to have one full csv file that contains all the translated sentences. I tried the below code:

```
out = pd.read_csv(path + 'en_tr_translated0.csv', sep='\t', names=['en_sentence', 'tr_sentence', 'translated_tr_sentence', 'translated_en_sentence'], dtype=str, encoding='utf-8', low_memory=False)
##
i = 1000

for _ in tqdm(range(200000)):
    new = pd.read_csv(path + f'en_tr_translated{i}.csv', sep='\t', names=['en_sentence', 'tr_sentence', 'translated_tr_sentence', 'translated_en_sentence'], dtype=str, encoding='utf-8', low_memory=False)
    out.loc[_, 'translated_tr_sentence'] = new.loc[_, 'translated_tr_sentence']
    out.loc[_, 'translated_en_sentence'] = new.loc[_, 'translated_en_sentence']
    if _ == i:
        i += 1000
```

Actually, it works fine but my problem is, it takes 105 HOURS!!

Is there any faster way to do this? I have to do this for like 5 different datasets and this is getting very annoying.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input files have one row of data exactly as one row in the file, correct? So it would probably be even faster if you don't even use pandas. Although if done correctly 200.000 should be still very fast no matter if using pandas or not.

For doing it without: Just open each file, move to the fitting index, write 1000 lines to the output file. Then move on to next file. You might have to fix headers etc. and look out that there is no shift in the indices, but here is an idea of how to do that:

```
with open(path + 'en_tr_translated_combined.csv', 'w') as f_out: # open out file in write modus
    for filename_index in tqdm(range(0, 201000, 1000)): # iterate over each index in steps of 1000 between 0 and 200000
        with open(path + f'en_tr_translated{filename_index}.csv') as f_in: # open file with that index
            for row_index, line in enumerate(f_in): # iterate over its rows
                if row_index < filename_index: # skip rows until you reached the ones with content in translation
                    continue
                if row_index > filename_index + 1000: # close the file if you reached the part where the translations end
                    break
                f_out.write(line) # for the inbetween: copy the content to out file
```

Comment: Good point, for "row" operation without complex filtering probably using pandas is overkill

Comment: Thank you very much for your clever advice. It was really really fast. However, it did a strange thing. In my output csv file, only some of the specific rows are filled. And it is in an incremental way. For example the only filled rows are: 1 - 1000 - 1001 - 2000 - 2001 -2002 - 3000 - 3001 - 3002 - 3003 .... etc. It goes up to the end. Rest of the rows are still empty.

Comment: I got it, it is about my data. Your code works perfectly and fast. I am accepting it as an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would load all the files, drop the rows that are not fully filled, and afterwards concatenate all of the dataframes.

Something like:

```
dfs = []
for ff in Path('.').rglob('*.csv'):
    dfs.append((pd.read_csv(ff, names=['en_sentence', 'tr_sentence', 'translated_tr_sentence', 'translated_en_sentence'], dtype=str, encoding='utf-8', low_memory=True).dropna())
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: Yeah it was amazingly fast but it duplicated the first two column entries (which is already filled in all csvs) and in the final output, row length became 200.000*200

Comment: if you are doing dropna it should not, rows that have _any_ item empty would be deleted, only rows where all columns have values would be kept

Comment: I did dropna but still happens

Comment: I would have to play with the data to see why. `.dropna(index=0, how='any')` should drop rows with any empty columns. Unless the empty fields are not being understood as NAs for some reason.